# Unit testing two lists and if there is a difference, print/show it

Tags: python, unit-testing

I started yesterday with unit testing in Python. I saw examples online that test with assertEqual who automatically print out the differences between both lists. However, it seems not to happen in my script. How can I obtain that?

The code below is contained in a class derived from unittest.TestCase:

```
def test_compare_two_lists_should_fail(self):
    a = [1,2,3] # In my actual code this is generated by a module's function
    b = [1,2,4]

    self.assertListEqual(a, b, 'lists are inequal')

def test_compare_two_lists_should_not_fail(self):
    a = [1,2,3] # In my actual code this is generated by a module's function
    b = [1,2,3]

    self.assertListEqual(a ,b, 'lists are inequal')
```

When running this test, it results in the following output:

test_compare_two_lists_should_not_fail (**main**.TestCase) ... ok
test_compare_two_lists_should_fail (**main**.TestCase) ... FAIL

======================================================================

### FAIL: test_compare_two_lists_should_fail (**main**.TestCase)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/some_dir/TestCase.py", line 34, in test_compare_two_lists_should_fail
    self.assertListEqual(a, b, 'lists are inequal')
AssertionError: lists are ineaqual

---

Ran 2 tests in 0.001s

FAILED (failures=1)

Comment: as Pynchia pointed out you have assertListEqual at both places, which gives you an expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the message you specify in both calls to `assertListEqual`.

From [these docs](http://nullege.com/codes/search/unittest.TestCase.assertListEqual)

> Args:
>
> list1: The first list to compare.
>
> list2: The second list to compare.
>
> msg: Optional message to use on failure instead of a list of differences.

So if you want to see the differences between the lists, avoid passing the message:

```
self.assertListEqual(a ,b)
```

By the way, you have the same `lists are inequal` message in both tests.

Comment: Sometimes it can be that simple as in leaving out the msg argument. Overlooked that by diving into the unit testing. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 3):

If you are starting with unit tests in Python, I suggest you to use `pytest`. IMHO, it is easier to use and the fail messages are smarter than `xUnit`.

With `pytest` you would get something like this:

```
def testFoo():
    assert [1, 2, 3] == [1, 2, 4], 'lists are inequal'
```

As a result:

```
================================== FAILURES ===================================
___________________________________ testFoo ___________________________________

    def testFoo():
>       assert [1, 2, 3] == [1, 2, 4]
E       AssertionError: lists are inequal
E       assert [1, 2, 3] == [1, 2, 4]
E         At index 2 diff: 3 != 4
E         Use -v to get the full diff

File "foo.py", line 2
AssertionError
========================== 1 failed in 0.07 seconds ===========================
```

Pretty easy writing it and pretty obvious the message. Give it a try!

Comment: thank you, it is probably something I should look into as well.

Comment: And it works like a charm! I meanwhile moved from WIndows to Ubuntu, which makes it much much easier to use command line tools :-) Thank you again.